# Change CSS of DIV with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML

```
<div class="content" id="content2">text<br></div>
```

and want to, for example, change CSS or just show Alert.

```
var chan = document.getElementById("content2");

if(chan){
  chan.addEventListener('click', function swapper() {
   alert('Ready!');
   //document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
})};
```

Why doesn't work? What I need to read?

Comment: Show us a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer using some code like this to change the css styles at (e.g) click-event:

```js
function addEventListener() {     
   var element = document.getElementById("content2");
   element.addEventListener('click', function swapper() {

       element.style.color = "red" // change the text color

       element.style.background = "black" // change the background color

       element.style.fontSize = "20px" // change the background color
  })
}


window.onload = function() {
   addEventListener()
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content2">click this text<br></div>
```

**Edit:** Keep in mind to use some unload-trigger (event) like `window.onload` to avoid issues:

```
window.onload = function() {

  // code to add event listeners, etc.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your code in [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to make sure the DOM has loaded first before you attempt to manipulate it's elements.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var chan = document.getElementById('content2')

  chan.addEventListener('click', function swapper() {
    alert('Ready!')
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="content2">Click me</div>
```

Comment: You are assuming that the script is placed before the element in the DOM. Though it's very likely, that may not be the case. Impossible to tell with OPs limited information.

Comment: That's what I'm assuming, yes. The simplest explanation is usually the right one; I also took a hint from that defensive `if` he has.

Comment: It would be better to wait for actual information rather than guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - You can wait for as long as you see fit.